# Which is the easiest Python web application framework to get started with, for general use?

Tags: python, web-frameworks

Which is the easiest Python web application framework to get started with, for general use?

Referring to easiest - I mean one which a short learning curve / time, at least in order to be able to use it for fairly simple apps. I have worked on non-trivial Ruby on Rails projects earlier, so it is not that I can't learn a more complex framework, it's just that for this particular app, I do not want to spend a lot of time learning the framework that I use - since this is more of an experimental app to test the idea - see below for more on that. If it turns out that the app idea is useful, I have no problem about later changing to a different framework and rewriting the entire app in that, after learning that framework properly.

I want to create a small web app - a personal productivity tool. Initially at least, it will be only for my personal use, though later I may consider opening it up to use by others, under whatever terms. Right now, I just want to prototype the idea and then use it some, myself, on a day-to-day basis, for a while, to get a feel for whether the app is actually useful or not for my productivity. By "general use" (in the title of this question), I mean that the suggested Python web app framework should not be specialized to any particular area, such as, say, Zope *may* (not sure) be more suited for creating CMS's (Content Management Systems). Also, the framework preferably should not put restrictions on what I can do, except for any restrictions that may be inherent in, or common to, all web app frameworks. (As an example of that last statement, the HTTP request/response cycle is, I guess, common to all, so all web app frameworks, whether in Python or not, put that restriction on the user/developer, that they have to implement their app in that style. Oh yes, and the framework should support creating database-backed web apps (which I guess most do, but mentioning it anyway). I should mention that I have tried out CherryPy (with SQLite) a little - not enough yet to decide whether it is suitable or not, also had some errors which I am working on resolving, but am anyway looking for other suggestions as well.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion. Read http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks for a long list. Most popular is probably Django.

Comment: Do you even want a web framework? Personally, for some small projects I just go bare bones `mod_python`.

Comment: Either Django or CherryPy.  The design goals are a little different.

Comment: @Andrew Lee: Thanks for the suggestion. In fact, just after I posted the original question, I thought why not just plain Python + the CGI module to start with, and then switch to a lightweight framework after doing at least some prototyping. But had not thought of mod_python as an option. Will explore that.

Answer (score 8):

I think you'll find [web2py](http://www.web2py.com) to be one of the easiest to set up, learn, and use (those are among its [primary goals](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/00)). It makes it easy to do simple things (and even many complex things), but still has a great deal of power and flexibility. It was [inspired by Rails](http://www.web2py.com/examples/default/what), so your familiarity with Rails may make it even easier to pick up. If you have any questions, there's a very helpful and responsive [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).

There was a recent review in InfoWorld: [[Overview](http://www.infoworld.com/d/application-development/pillars-python-six-python-web-frameworks-compared-169442) | [web2py](http://www.infoworld.com/d/application-development/pillars-python-web2py-web-framework-168920?page=0,0&1313029958=)]. And a recent [presentation](http://www.scribd.com/doc/60038745/web2py-talk).

Answer (score 5):

Django is by far the most popular. Documentation is excellent, which will help you get up and running.

Comment: I second Django, since this is probably the easiest framework to learn.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some "it fits in my brain" Python web frameworks

- [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)
- [webapp2](http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/)
- [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/)

These all lack ORMs, but you are free to use one of your choice (sqlalchemy, Storm) etc.

Answer (score 3):

[web.py](http://webpy.org/) is probably the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Plone is probably the simplest, but Django is the most popular. It's also extremely well documented.

Comment: I would not consider Plone as the **simplest**; Zope/Plone are the heavyweight, but also most feature rich Python web frameworks. Django lacks many, many of the features Zope/Plone has!

Comment: Yeah? Maybe my perception is skewed because I picked up Plone in a few hours and it was the first one I learned, but Django seemed to take me a few days to get the hang of it and I learned it later.